# Getting a 'list index out of range' when trying to read information from a csv

Tags: python, csv

I'm working in this python code:

```python
import csv

f = open('classA.csv')

csv_f = csv.reader(f)

newlist = []

for row in csv_f:
    # Convert all to int
    row[2] = int(row[2])
    row[3] = int(row[3])
    row[4] = int(row[4])
    # Assign Lowest
    minimum = min(row[2:4])
    row.append(minimum)
    # Assign Max
    maximum = max(row[2:4])
    row.append(maximum)
    # Assign Average
    average = round(sum(row[2:4]) / 3)
    row.append(average)
    # Add all to newlist
    newlist.append(row[0:10])

lowScore = [[x[5], x[0], x[1]] for x in newlist]

print("\nLowest Scores By Student \n")

for entry in sorted(lowScore):
    print(entry)
print("\n")

averageScore = [[x[7], x[0], x[1]] for x in newlist]

print("\nHighest Average Scores By Student \n")

for entry in sorted(averageScore, reverse=True):
    print(entry)
```

Here is my .csv file content:

```
Oliver,H,0,0,0
Sean,E,1,0,0
Tom,C,1,0,0
```

I have tried for at least an hour to figure this out, it is probably a stupid mistake on my part.

So as I said. I am getting a `list index out of range` when running this program, so any help would be greatly appreciated.

**Complete traceback:**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "N:\GCSE Computing\Programming CA\Task 3\Task 3 - Solo.py", line 51, in <module>
    row[2] = int(row[2])
IndexError: list index out of range
```

Comment: Can you paste the complete traceback you're getting? I've just tried your code and it worked fine for me.

Comment: Sure, I have just added it.

Comment: Code seems to work just fine for me as well, could you double check your csv contents?

Comment: Working fine for me, too. The error is on line 51, but the code you posted doesn't have 51 lines... if you run the exact code you posted here, does it still generate the same error?

Comment: I have just ran the exact code posted here, I am still receiving this error. The reason why it says 51 lines is because in the full code I have a lot of comments, I did not include these here.

Comment: Okay, I did make a stupid mistake, There was a line in the csv missing a comma. It works fine now. Thanks for the help though guys.

Comment: You should add a length check and skip an entry if it is not long enough. Maybe print a warning